# is it possible to set column value to a concatenation of string and iteration value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to set value of a varchar column to a concatenation of a string and the result set iteration.

for example:

```
update TB_USER set LOGIN_NAME = 'BOB'+index where LOGIN_NAME = 'BOB'
```

results in the following:

> LOGIN_NAME
>
> BOB0
>
> BOB1
>
> BOB2

Comment: are you expecting this to be inside a stored procedure?

Comment: no, Im just trying to execute a simple query to update some values which cannot be deleted because of constraints

Comment: Yes, except `index` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update T
SET LOGIN_NAME = LOGIN_NAME + CAST(rn AS varchar(10))
FROM
   (SELECT
       LOGIN_NAME,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something /*or (SELECT 1)/*) as rn
    FROM
       TB_USER
    WHERE
       LOGIN_NAME = 'Bob'
    ) T
```